# My indoor strawberry plants stopped producing runners, could fertilizer be the reason?

Tags: fertilizer, propagation, strawberries, phosphorous, stress

I germinated some strawberry seeds from strawberries that I bought from the fruit guy on the corner sometime in October of last year. Once the plants got big enough to flower, they started producing runners. I went on holiday and the plants had some water stress where a few died. The one that was making runners and seems to grow the prettiest strawberries, completely stopped shooting runners, but they're making a bunch of strawberries.

I've been feeding the plants high phosphorus fertilizer, could that be the culprit?
If I switch to a high nitrogen fertilizer and cut off all of the flowers, will it start shooting runners again?

Answer (score 1):

No, I think it is normal. Now the plants are fruiting (and it had some water stress), so they put energy on fruits. When it finish fruiting it will make much more runners (and often longer).

Comment: The thing is, they seem to be everbearing, so they just keep flowering. Being they came from a commercial strawberry, their habits are unpredictable. There are still no runners and they've been fruiting for well over a season despite switching to a 10-5-14 fertilizer .

Comment: I was just watching a video on youtube where the guy said strawberries like to fruit when it's cooler and exhibits more vegetative growth over the hotter months. Could it be they're growing in an airconditioned room? The last time I saw runners it was cold out, so it was much warmer in the room.